# Strange AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter assumptions

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

I've investigated Spring Security implementations associated with AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and I have to admit that I'm quite confused. Let's focus on method called requiresAuthentication, because based on value returned by it authentication will or will not be performed.

Due to:

```
if (currentUser.getName().equals(principal)) {
   return false;
}
```

authentication will never be performed when equals principal is stored in SecurityContextHolder (thread local). It is quite valid scenario when such a situation will occur. What will happen next? Filter assumes that same principal (authenticated in the past) does not require to be authenticated again. What if logic implemented in AuthenticationProvider is crucial and assignable Authorities might change quickly over time?

I understand that this "behavior" can be easily bypassed by implementing any class (since principal is referenced as Object) which does not override Object's equals method. Still, I'd like to make sure what do I miss, because from my current point of view it is quite a bug. If my doubts are correct, then all of following implementations might lead to security issue:

- J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
- WebSpherePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
- RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter

X509AuthenticationFilter works correctly since two different X509Certificate are never equals.

Robert

Comment: It tries to solve the 80% case and that will not suite everyone. It basically follows what the rest of the framework does (only re-authenticate on a principal change). If you require re-authentication on each request, override the `doFilter` method (just noticed that the `requiresAuthentication` is private and as such cannot be overriden).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! What concerns me the most is the fact that in public infrastructure (such as Internet) it is possible to use "cached" Authentication implementation's instance to perform operations w/o authorization. As a result usage of default implementations might lead to security hole :(. Even that I believe it's out responsibility to dig into frameworks we use, it is not good situation (imho).

I've already implemented my own filter few days ago, so basically I've followed your advice :).

Comment: I don't really follow your argument here. The point of the pre-authentication infrastructure is that the authentication is performed externally. For normal usage, there's no security hole in using a principal cached in the current session.

Comment: That's right, but then authorities are not assigned based on up to date (implementation of AuthenticationProvider) data but loaded from SecurityContextHolder instead.

Comment: That's not something that's specific to pre-authentication. Almost every session-based web application on the internet will log you in for the duration of the session, however long that may be, rather than re-authenticate for every request.